# What is the correct way to use multiple snapshot listeners in Firestore for the purpose of lazy loading and infinite scroll (Firebase + React)?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, lazy-loading

Every time the user scrolls to the bottom of the screen, a new array of products is loaded in and added to the products array using setProducts. Along with this, a new snapshot listener is created to allow for real-time updates for those products. Each new snapshot listener is added to the unsubListenerFunctions piece of state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingMore && lastVisible) {
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
        query(
          collection(db, 'products'),
          orderBy('productName', 'asc'),
          startAfter(lastVisible),
          limit(2)
        ),
        snapshot => {
          setProducts(prev => prev.concat(snapshot.docs));
          setLastVisible(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]);
          setLoadingMore(false);
        }
      );

      setUnsubListenerFunctions(prev => [...prev, unsubscribe]);
    } else setLoadingMore(false);
  }, [loadingMore]);
```

The new products correctly appear on the feed: https://i.gyazo.com/6b297d9775005ffa95dcc633146d160a.mp4

**ISSUE:**
The issue occurs when a product that is not in the original load is edited. The real-time update breaks and that same snapshot is reloaded and added to the feed:
https://i.gyazo.com/3f587422b81caf24b56a07a7ed5798ef.mp4

The outcome is the same if the product is edited directly from the Firestore web console.

Ideally, I would like to have the same product item updated correctly without reloading that entire snapshot and adding them to the feed. I am unsure if this is the correct way to unsubscribe from multiple snapshot listeners. I would appreciate any assistance with this, this is my first attempt at lazy loading with real-time data.

I've pasted the index.js file (homepage) here (excluding the JSX):

```
export default function Home() {
  const { logout, currentUser } = useAuth();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadingMore, setLoadingMore] = useState(false);
  const [unsubListenerFunctions, setUnsubListenerFunctions] = useState([]);
  const [showGoToTop, setShowGoToTop] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      query(
        collection(db, 'products'),
        orderBy('productName', 'asc'),
        limit(6)
      ),
      snapshot => {
        setProducts(snapshot.docs);
        setLastVisible(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]);
        loading && setLoading(false);
      }
    );

    setUnsubListenerFunctions([unsubscribe]);

    return () => {
      unsubListenerFunctions.forEach(unsub => unsub());
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingMore && lastVisible) {
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
        query(
          collection(db, 'products'),
          orderBy('productName', 'asc'),
          startAfter(lastVisible),
          limit(2)
        ),
        snapshot => {
          setProducts(prev => prev.concat(snapshot.docs));
          setLastVisible(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]);
          setLoadingMore(false);
        }
      );

      setUnsubListenerFunctions(prev => [...prev, unsubscribe]);
    } else setLoadingMore(false);
  }, [loadingMore]);

  const handleScroll = e => {
    if (e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 200) {
      setShowGoToTop(true);
    } else {
      setShowGoToTop(false);
    }

    if (loadingMore) return;

    const bottomReached =
      e.target.scrollingElement.scrollHeight -
        e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop <=
      e.target.scrollingElement.clientHeight + 100;

    if (bottomReached) {
      setLoadingMore(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="" onScroll={handleScroll}>

        ...

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of mitigating this problem that I found to be successful - Load the data up front using a firestore `getDocs` call. Once that call has finished, make your onSnapshot call as you normally would. Once the snapshot listener is finished setting up, there likely won't be much of a change in data from your initial fetch. Below is how you might implement this solution.

```
export default function Home() {
  const { logout, currentUser } = useAuth();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadingMore, setLoadingMore] = useState(false);
  const [unsubListenerFunctions, setUnsubListenerFunctions] = useState([]);
  const [showGoToTop, setShowGoToTop] = useState(false);

  const [initialProductsLoaded, setInitialProductsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);



  useEffect(() => {
      getDocs(query(
        collection(db, 'products'),
        orderBy('productName', 'asc'),
        limit(6)
      )).then((querySnapshot) => {
        setProducts(snapshot.docs);
        setLastVisible(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]);
        loading && setLoading(false);
        setInitialProductsLoaded(true);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialProductsLoaded) {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      query(
        collection(db, 'products'),
        orderBy('productName', 'asc'),
        limit(6)
      ),
      snapshot => {
        setProducts(snapshot.docs);
        setLastVisible(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]);
      }
    );

    setUnsubListenerFunctions([unsubscribe]);

    return () => {
      unsubListenerFunctions.forEach(unsub => unsub());
    };
    }

  }, [initialProductsLoaded]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingMore && lastVisible) {
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
        query(
          collection(db, 'products'),
          orderBy('productName', 'asc'),
          startAfter(lastVisible),
          limit(2)
        ),
        snapshot => {
          setProducts(prev => prev.concat(snapshot.docs));
          setLastVisible(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]);
          setLoadingMore(false);
        }
      );

      setUnsubListenerFunctions(prev => [...prev, unsubscribe]);
    } else setLoadingMore(false);
  }, [loadingMore]);

  const handleScroll = e => {
    if (e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 200) {
      setShowGoToTop(true);
    } else {
      setShowGoToTop(false);
    }

    if (loadingMore) return;

    const bottomReached =
      e.target.scrollingElement.scrollHeight -
        e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop <=
      e.target.scrollingElement.clientHeight + 100;

    if (bottomReached) {
      setLoadingMore(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="" onScroll={handleScroll}>

        ...

    </div>
  );
}
```

Before this solution, I had very little luck with setting up multiple snapshot listeners at once. Commenting out all but one listener gave me the result of a very quick load, but as soon as I had more than one listener, it would result in a 7-10 second load time. Hope this is helpful!